# Error in SQL when using coalesce to get number of items(comments) related to a post

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on a SQL where I need to get number of comments on every post. I have three tables to use here users, posts and comments. posts and comments have postid as foreign key.

I am getting following error when I tried to get the comments count:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM posts, users where users.userid = posts.userid and posts.userid = 16 order ' at line 1

My SQL:

```sql
SELECT
  postid,
  post,
  type,
  users.userid,
  CONCAT( firstname, ' ', lastname ) as name,
  COALESCE(
    (SELECT
       COUNT(*)
     FROM comments
     WHERE postid = posts.postid
    ),
  0) AS cnt,
FROM
  posts,
  users
where
  users.userid = posts.userid and
  posts.userid = 16
order by
  postid desc
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, learn to use proper `JOIN` syntax.  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.

Second, table aliases and qualified column names make a query easier to write and to read.

```
SELECT p.postid, p.post, p.type, u.userid,
       CONCAT_WS(' ',  u.firstname, u.lastname ) as name,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comments c WHERE c.postid = p.postid) AS cnt
FROM posts JOIN
     users u
     ON u.userid = p.userid and p.userid = 16
ORDER BY p.postid desc;
```

(I am guessing at the tables where the columns come from.(

In addition:

- The `COALESCE()` is unnecessary.  `COUNT(*)` does not return `NULL`.
- The extra comma was the specific problem in your query.
- If `firstname` is missing, then your version will have `name` start with a space.  `CONCAT_WS()` fixes this problem.

Comment: All right, I will always use JOIN syntax from now on, thanks for helping me learn new things about sql

Answer (score 4):

You actually don't need to use `COALESCE`:

```
SELECT postid, post, type, users.userid, 
       CONCAT( firstname, ' ', lastname ) as name, 
       (SELECT COUNT( * ) 
        FROM comments 
        WHERE postid = posts.postid) AS cnt
FROM posts
JOIN users ON users.userid = posts.userid 
where posts.userid = 16 
order by postid desc
```

`COUNT` will return `0` in case there are no records.

**Note:** Use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax instead of old-fashioned implicit syntax.

Comment: @Jordan [Here](https://www.linkedin.com/in/giorgos-betsos-1a53638?trk=hp-identity-name) you are.

Answer (score 2):

remove comma `,` before from

```
SELECT postid, post, type, users.userid, 
        CONCAT( firstname, ' ', lastname ) as name, 
        COALESCE(( SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM comments WHERE postid = posts.postid), 0 ) AS cnt
FROM posts, users 
where users.userid = posts.userid and posts.userid = 16 
order by postid desc
```

Comment: that was a terrible mistake from me, thanks for pointing it.